# Replace value with the mean based on two classes

Tags: r, pivot, mean

I have a `dataset` with 2 calendar variables (`Week` & `Hour`) and 1 `Amount` variable:

```
 Week Hour Amount
   35    1    367
   35    2    912
   36    1    813
   36    2    482
   37    1    112
   37    2    155
   35    1    182
   35    2    912
   36    1    551
   36    2    928
   37    1    125
   37    2    676
```

I wish to replace each value of `Amount` with the mean from each observation with the same Week/Hour pair. For instance, here there are 2 obs. for (`Week=35`, `Hour=1`), with `Amount` values of `367` and `182`. Hence, for this example, the 2 rows with (`Week=35`, `Hour=1`) should have the `Amount` replaced with `mean(c(367,182)`. The final output should be:

```
Week Hour Amount
  35    1  274.5
  35    2  912.0
  36    1  682.0
  36    2  705.0
  37    1  118.5
  37    2  415.5
  35    1  274.5
  35    2  912.0
  36    1  682.0
  36    2  705.0
  37    1  118.5
  37    2  415.5
```

I have the following code that solves this issue. However, for the complete dataset with thousands of rows, it is very slow. Is there any way to automatically reshape with with this paired means?

```
dataset = data.frame(Week=c(35,35,36,36,37,37,35,35,36,36,37,37),
                     Hour = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                     Amount = c(367,912,813,482,112,155,182,912,551,928,125,676))

means <- reshape2::dcast(dataset, Week~Hour, value.var="Value", mean)

for (i in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
  print(i)
  dataset$Amount[i] <- means[means$Week==dataset$Week[i],which(colnames(means)==dataset$Hour[i])]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution with `dplyr`:

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(Week, Hour) %>% 
  summarise(mean_amount = mean(Amount))
```

You group by Week and Hour and calculate the mean based on this condition.

**EDIT**

To keep the original structure (number of rows) alter the code to

```
dataset %>% 
  group_by(Week, Hour) %>% 
  mutate(Amount = mean(Amount))
```

Comment: But that's not really what the OP wants.

Comment: Edited, now it should be what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is just to get the mean `Amount` by `Week` and `Hour`, this would work:

```
aggregate(Amount ~ ., dataset, mean)
  Week Hour Amount
1   35    1  274.5
2   36    1  682.0
3   37    1  118.5
4   35    2  912.0
5   36    2  705.0
6   37    2  415.5
```

**EDIT**:

If, however, the idea is to put the averages back into the `dataset`, then this should work:

```
x <- aggregate(Amount ~ ., dataset, mean)
dataset$Amount <- x$Amount[match(apply(dataset[,1:2], 1, paste0, collapse = " "), 
                                 apply(x[,1:2], 1, paste0, collapse = " "))]
dataset
   Week Hour Amount
1    35    1  274.5
2    35    2  912.0
3    36    1  682.0
4    36    2  705.0
5    37    1  118.5
6    37    2  415.5
7    35    1  274.5
8    35    2  912.0
9    36    1  682.0
10   36    2  705.0
11   37    1  118.5
12   37    2  415.5
```

Explanation:

This `paste`s together into strings the rows of the first two columns in the means dataframe `x` and in `dataset`using the function `apply` it uses `match` on these strings to assign the means values to the corresponding rows in `dataset`

**EDIT 2**:

Alternatively, you can use `interaction` and, respectively, `%in%` for this transformation:

```
dataset$Amount <- x$Amount[match(interaction(dataset[,1:2]), interaction(x[,1:2]))]
# or:
dataset$Amount <- x$Amount[interaction(x[,1:2]) %in% interaction(dataset[,1:2])]
```

Comment: I've added two more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
dataset$Amount <- with(dataset, ave(dataset$Amount, dataset$Week, dataset$Hour, FUN = mean))
```

Data:

```
dataset = data.frame(Week=c(35,35,36,36,37,37,35,35,36,36,37,37),
                     Hour = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                     Amount = c(367,912,813,482,112,155,182,912,551,928,125,676))
```